# Swap elements of tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a surprisingly hard time trying to swap elements of a tensor with variable length. From what I understand, sliced assignment is only supported for variables, thus when running the following code, I get the error `ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables`.

```
def add_noise(tensor):
  length = tf.size(tensor)

  i = tf.random_uniform((), 0, length-2, dtype=tf.int32)
  aux = tensor[i]
  tensor = tensor[i].assign(tensor[i+1])
  tensor = tensor[i+1].assign(aux)

  return tensor

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=tf.int32)
  print sess.run(add_noise(tensor))
```

How can I swap elements in a tensor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TensorFlow **scatter** function [`scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) for swapping `tensor` elements. You can also achieve multiple swaps in a single `scatter` operation.

```
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=tf.int32)  # input
# let's swap 1st and 4th elements, and also 5th and 6th elements (in terms of 0-based indexing)
indices = tf.constant([[0], [4], [2], [3], [1], [5], [6]])  # indices mentioning the swapping pattern
shape = tf.shape(tensor)  # shape of the scattered_tensor, zeros will be injected if output shape is greater than input shape
scattered_tensor = tf.scatter_nd(indices, tensor, shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run(scattered_tensor)
  # [0 4 2 3 1 6 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensors are immutable once they are defined, on the other hand Variables are mutable. What you need is a TensorFlow variable.You should change the line:

`tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(l, dtype=tf.int32)`

to the following.

`tensor = tf.Variable(l, dtype=tf.int32, name='my_variable')`

Comment: I want `tensor` to be a tf.Tensor, not a tf.Variable. it is fine if I create a new tensor with the values I want.

Comment: To best of my knowledge, the `tensor` needs to be a `Variable` because swapping requires either `assign` operation or `scatter_update` method, and both require a TensorFlow variable. 

The other method would be to define a TensorFlow variable and do the swapping and then convert it to a tensor through `convert_to_tensor`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to swap a different pair for each row of a matrix.

```
def batch_column_swap(base_tensor, from_col_index, to_col_index):
  batch_size = tf.shape(base_tensor)[0]
  batch_range = tf.range(batch_size)
  from_col_index = tf.stack([batch_range, from_col_index], axis=1)
  to_col_index = tf.stack([batch_range, to_col_index], axis=1)
  indices = tf.concat([to_col_index, from_col_index], axis=0)
  from_col = tf.gather_nd(base_tensor, from_col_index)
  to_col = tf.gather_nd(base_tensor, to_col_index)
  updates = tf.concat([from_col, to_col], axis=0)
  return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(base_tensor, indices, updates)

base_tensor = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
from_col_idx = [0, 1]
to_col_idx = [1, 0]
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(batch_column_swap(base_tensor, from_col_idx, to_col_idx))

# array([[1, 0],
#        [3, 2]], dtype=int32)
```